# How to remove attribution in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, attribution

I want to remove the `"Leaflet.com"` that appears on the right bottom of the screen
here. How can I do that?

[image: example]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The Leaflet way: `L.map('map', {attributionControl: false, etc...})`

A simple `$('.leaflet-control-attribution').hide()` or non jQuery `document.getElementsByClassName( 'leaflet-control-attribution' )[0].style.display = 'none';`.

Vladimir himself says it's OK to remove it: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/leaflet-js/fA6M7fbchOs/JTNVhqdc7JcJ, but it seems like you should leave it or acknowledge Leaflet in some way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution worked for me!!

Comment: Thanks for sharing Vladimirs comment!
Here is a way to only remove the `Leaflet` prefix: `map.attributionControl.setPrefix(false)` 
https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution-prefix

Answer (score 12):

This is perfectly explained in the [Leaflet API reference for attribution control](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#control-attribution).

Answer (score 8):

For those using [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/), use:

```
<Map attributionControl={false} />
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just wanna remove "*Leaflet*" prefix then :

```
map.attributionControl.setPrefix('YOUR_ATTRIBUTION')
```

Where `map` is an object returned by `L.map(...)` call.

Comment: I like the attribution coupled with my tileLayer (I use OpenStreetMap), so I call `map.attributionControl.setPrefix()` with empty args to remove the Leaflet attribution

Answer (score 0):

tutorial [here](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/issues/117)

```
(leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event);"
  [leafletOptions]="options"


  import { Layer, tileLayer, Map, control } from 'leaflet';
  ...
  options: any = {};
  constructor() {
    this.options['attributionControl'] = false;
  }
  ...
  onMapReady(map: Map) {
    map.addControl(
        control.attribution({
            position: 'bottomright',
            prefix: ''
        })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use leaflet on Angular you can disable it at this way:

```
this.map = new Map('mapId', {attributionControl: false});
```